# How can I prove that $(x+1)^x \leq x^{x+1}$ for all $x > 2$?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I was playing around with this inequality for natural numbers, and it appears that for $x=1$ and $x=2$, the inequality is false, but for all other numbers, it seems to be true. I verified this graphically, but I'm still not 100% sure that it's true, i.e. if there's some very large number for which the inequality is false. Any ideas how to prove (or disprove + possibly find the counterexample) this?

Comment: You must mean for all **integer** $x>2$? with any $2 < x < e$ this is not true...

Comment: Yes, I did mean for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, I forgot to clarify that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^{x+1}}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{x}}_{\le 1/3}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x}_{ \le e} \le \frac{e}{3}<1.
$$

Comment: Is inequality true if $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Nope: the inequality is false for $x \in \{1,2\}$. However it holds, strictly, for all reals $x \ge e$.